# Skip stages in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkinsfile

I am using a scripted pipeline where I am required to skip some stages conditionally.Is there a way to show skipped stages on Jenkins UI other than importing **org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils** in the jenkinsfile as the import is giving me "cannot resolve class" error while running build.gradle for some other script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no way to visualize skipped stages in the Jenkins UI.  [See this issue report on the Jenkins JIRA about visualizing skipped stages](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54322?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel).

There are a few workarounds that I'm aware of:

You can [disable the Groovy sandbox](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#groovy-sandbox) to allow importing the aforementioned class.

You can also use the [imperative-when plugin](https://github.com/comquent/imperative-when) for scripted Pipelines as described in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Lopay/how-to-skip-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline-f653e54d835d) to add visualization (note that I haven't tested this personally).

Or you can skip the visualization altogether and wrap your build steps in an if clause to conditionally execute them.  You'll see in the Jenkins UI that a stage takes 0ms to execute if it has no steps, so there's at least some indication that it was skipped even if it doesn't explicitly say "skipped".

Comment: My issue got resolved by importing org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.*  instead of org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils